# How to power off a Debian server and a UPS on low battery?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ups

How to configure a Debian server with one standalone USB UPS to:

1. Initiate a UPS power off after one minute when the battery is low.
2. Shutdown itself.
3. And to be sure that when mains power is restored (**even before the UPS runs out**) the Debian server will start.

These steps are described in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/313630/how-to-wake-a-server-after-ups-shuts-it-down-when-mains-power-is-restored) but there is no explanation how to achieve them.

I have:

- My server configured to always start when the power is restored.
- Installed `nut` and when I run `upsc myups` I see the info from the UPS, including the battery level. So I can easily write a script to monitor the battery and shutdown the server.

My question is:

#### How to send a power off command to the UPS?

The UPS is: **EATON 5E 650i**

In `/etc/nut/nut.conf` I have:

```
MODE=standalone
```

In `/etc/nut/ups.conf` I have:

```
[myups]
    driver = usbhid-ups
    port = auto
    vendorid = 0463
    pollfreq = 30
```

`upsc myups` prints:

```
Init SSL without certificate database
battery.charge: 100
battery.runtime: 1825
battery.type: PbAc
device.mfr: EATON
device.model: 5E 650i
device.type: ups
driver.name: usbhid-ups
driver.parameter.pollfreq: 30
driver.parameter.pollinterval: 2
driver.parameter.port: auto
driver.parameter.synchronous: no
driver.parameter.vendorid: 0463
driver.version: 2.7.4
driver.version.data: MGE HID 1.39
driver.version.internal: 0.41
input.voltage: 230.0
outlet.1.status: on
outlet.desc: Main Outlet
outlet.id: 1
outlet.switchable: no
output.frequency: 49.9
output.frequency.nominal: 50
output.voltage: 230.0
output.voltage.nominal: 230
ups.beeper.status: enabled
ups.delay.shutdown: 20
ups.firmware: 03.08.0018
ups.load: 19
ups.mfr: EATON
ups.model: 5E 650i
ups.power.nominal: 650
ups.productid: ffff
ups.start.battery: yes
ups.status: OL
ups.timer.shutdown: -1
ups.vendorid: 0463
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think it is working now.
Here is what I did:

`apt-get install nut-server`

`apt-get install nut-client`

`nano /etc/nut/nut.conf`

```
MODE=standalone
```

`nano /etc/nut/ups.conf`

```
[myups]
    driver = usbhid-ups
    port = auto
    vendorid = 0463
    pollfreq = 30
```

`/sbin/upsdrvctl start`

`upsc myups`
Prints some problems.

Reboot
`/usr/sbin/shutdown -r now`

Now when you execute `upsc myups` you should see the info of your UPS:

```
Init SSL without certificate database
battery.charge: 86
battery.runtime: 956
battery.type: PbAc
device.mfr: EATON
device.model: 5E 650i
device.type: ups
driver.name: usbhid-ups
driver.parameter.pollfreq: 30
driver.parameter.pollinterval: 2
driver.parameter.port: auto
driver.parameter.synchronous: no
driver.parameter.vendorid: 0463
driver.version: 2.7.4
driver.version.data: MGE HID 1.39
driver.version.internal: 0.41
input.voltage: 226.0
outlet.1.status: on
outlet.desc: Main Outlet
outlet.id: 1
outlet.switchable: no
output.frequency: 49.9
output.frequency.nominal: 50
output.voltage: 225.0
output.voltage.nominal: 230
ups.beeper.status: enabled
ups.delay.shutdown: 20
ups.firmware: 03.08.0018
ups.load: 27
ups.mfr: EATON
ups.model: 5E 650i
ups.power.nominal: 650
ups.productid: ffff
ups.start.battery: yes
ups.status: OL
ups.timer.shutdown: -1
ups.vendorid: 0463
```

If `/sbin/upsmon` print something like:

```
Network UPS Tools upsmon 2.7.4
fopen /var/run/nut/upsmon.pid: No such file or directory
Using power down flag file /etc/killpower

Fatal error: insufficient power configured!

Sum of power values........: 0
Minimum value (MINSUPPLIES): 1

Edit your upsmon.conf and change the values.
```

try: `nano /etc/nut/upsd.users`

```
[upsmon]
    password  = mypassword
    upsmon master
```

`chmod 640 /etc/nut/upsd.users`

`ls -lahrt /etc/nut/upsd.users`

```
-rw-r----- 1 root nut 2,2K Dec 13 13:15 /etc/nut/upsd.users
```

`nano /etc/nut/upsmon.conf`

```
MONITOR myups@localhost 1 upsmon mypassword master
```

`systemctl enable nut-monitor`

`/sbin/upsmon`

```
Network UPS Tools upsmon 2.7.4
fopen /var/run/nut/upsmon.pid: No such file or directory
UPS: myups@localhost (master) (power value 1)
Using power down flag file /etc/killpower
```

Here is what can be seen in syslog when I tested by cutting off the electricity:

```
Dec 13 15:47:01 pc upsmon[604]: UPS myups@localhost on battery
... 12 minutes later
Dec 13 15:59:32 pc upsmon[604]: UPS myups@localhost battery is low
Dec 13 15:59:32 pc upsd[601]: Client upsmon@::1 set FSD on UPS [myups]
Dec 13 15:59:32 pc upsmon[604]: Executing automatic power-fail shutdown
Dec 13 15:59:32 pc upsmon[604]: Auto logout and shutdown proceeding
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: nut-monitor.service: Succeeded.
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Succeeded.
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopping Session 39 of user a.
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc upsd[601]: mainloop: Interrupted system call
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc upsd[601]: Signal 15: exiting
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopping Network UPS Tools - power devices information server...
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Succeeded.
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL Cluster...
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: sysstat.service: Succeeded.
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopped Resets System Activity Data Collector.
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc smartd[392]: smartd received signal 15: Terminated
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc smartd[392]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.xxx.ata.state
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc smartd[392]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.yyy.ata.state
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc smartd[392]: smartd is exiting (exit status 0)
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopping Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon...
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Dec 13 15:59:37 pc systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
... when power is on again
Dec 13 16:01:28 pc kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.19.0-9-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.1$
```

After the boot when I execute `upsmon` I see the following:

`/sbin/upsmon`

```
Network UPS Tools upsmon 2.7.4
Fatal error: A previous upsmon instance is already running!
Either stop the previous instance first, or use the 'reload' command.
```

Which means it is running and everything is fine, I guess  :)

You can see the meaning of the variables, printed by `upsc`, such as `ups.status`, `ups.timer.shutdown`, `battery.charge`, here: https://networkupstools.org/docs/user-manual.pdf

Another useful URL is: https://risc-a-day.blogspot.com/2014/09/getting-my-ups-to-work-with-linux.html